# SQL Connection code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

Here's my code for a SQL connection. Not sure if I have handled all errors. Instead of Using should I just use Try Catch block?

```cs
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetSQLConnectionString()))
{
    string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO table1.....";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con))
    {
        //Store parameters with values to the collection
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NAME", NAME);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID",ID);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

        if (con != null)
           con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: 6 questions - none accepted - you need to accept answers on some of your past questions - otherwise people will be far less inclined to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd re-write your current catch block to only catch [`SQLException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) - catching *any* `Exception` is rarely correct. This would also mean that you could produce prettier output (formatting each separate SQLError object), include a total error count, or react to specific errors that you know your code can handle.

A general rule for exception handling is to only catch exceptions that your code can correctly deal with at that point (hence the general avoidance of catching `Exception`). You'd generally install a single top level "unhandled Exception" handler in your app that will log other exceptions and shut down the app. If you don't know *what* the exception is, how can you hold a belief that your code can continue to operate successfully when it has occurred?

As Neil says, you don't need to explicitly close the connection since the `using` block guarantees this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Having a `catch` block from data-access talk to `lblError` tells me you have your UI code and your DB code too close together. I would *not* do that; my DB code would be simply:

```
using (var con = SomeUtilityCode.GetOpenConnection())
{
    string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO table1.....";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con))
    {
        //Store parameters with values to the collection
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NAME", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID",id);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

or perhaps something a lot cleaner using "dapper":

```
using (var con = SomeUtilityCode.GetOpenConnection())
{
    con.Execute("INSERT INTO table1.....", new { NAME = name, ID = id });
}
```

and my UI code would be

```
try
{
   someObject.SomeSensibleMethod(NAME, ID);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   ShowError(ex);
}
```

where `ShowError` tells the user about the problem (perhaps sanitized) without needing evert operation to know the UI details.

Answer (score 1):

The `try/catch` block is a good idea as the `using` won't catch any errors, it will just throw the exception and stop.

Also, in your `using` code, you don't need to do:

```
if (con != null)
    con.Close();
```

as this will be handled by the `using` statement.

Comment: I'm not convinced; it only makes sense here because the method is *already* fractured.